# how to extract list or bullet details from .pptx or .ppt file using c#

Tags: powerpoint

I am using Microsoft office Interope assembly to extract features from .pptx and .ppt files using c#. I was able to extract details about shapes, animations but not able to extract details about which types of bullets ppt or pptx consists of or which slide contains bullets etc.

Please help me finding this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, you'd do something like this to examine the bullets on slide 1

```
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim x As Long ' Integer in C#?
For Each oSh In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
    With oSh
        If .HasTextFrame Then
            If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                With .TextFrame2.TextRange
                    For x = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
                        Debug.Print .Paragraphs(x).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.[Various properties]

                    Next
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Look at the code in the PPT VBA editor. When you type the dot after Bullet above, intellisense will show you the available properties.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Now I will try to implement this in c#.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways.  In the code below, you can see the properties of the text that you can access in your program:

```
ppTextBox.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type =
    Office.MsoBulletType.msoBulletNumbered;
ppTextBox.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Style =
    Office.MsoNumberedBulletStyle.msoBulletAlphaLCParenBoth;

ppTextBox.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.StartValue = 4;
ppTextBox.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.UseTextColor =
    Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
ppTextBox.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.UseTextFont =
    Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```

where ppTextBox is a shape object, and note the use of TextFrame2 rather than TextFrame.  You can interrogate the ParagraphFormat.Bullt.Type against the enumerated list Office.MsoBulletType to see which has been applied.

For more details, check [this page](http://www.davidallenpollock.com/AutomatingPowerPoint.html) for more details on text processing in powerpoint with C#.